# Barcode scanner application on Raspberry Pi board

Tags: usb, camera

I am looking for suggestions related to my test project. I am trying to make a barcode scanner on Raspberry Pi.

I have bought the camera which is based on 1/2.8" Sony IMX290 CMOS sensor. This camera is a USB camera and we can connect this camera to the Raspberry Pi board over the USB port. I would be running Yocto linux on the Raspberry Pi board. I have familiarised myself to load image/board bring up on the Raspberry Pi board.

Next step, I would like the camera to scan the barcode, decode the information and send the information to another module.

Questions: Would a normal camera (already mentioned above) work for this project OR some special bar code scanner device is needed? If a normal camera would work, is there any documentation/links which I could follow?

Thanks a lot in advance for helping in this learning journey. :)

Admin, please tag the right tags, if needed.

Comment: Have a look at http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

For the complete workflow (decode image, send result elsewhere) you will need to invest some programming time, but the `zbar-tools` suite offers tools to read a camera stream and decode various codes found on the images, so you can take that as a starting point.